# How to dynamically change the image with animation using RajawaliVR

Tags: android, animation, rajawalivr

I am able to change image dynamically using this code :

```
public void changeImage()
    {
       Log.d("debug1", "" + getCurrentScene().getNumChildren());
        ArrayList<Object3D> objectList = getCurrentScene().getChildrenCopy();
        Material material = objectList.get(0).getMaterial();
        for (ATexture texture : material.getTextureList())
        {
            material.removeTexture(texture);
            texture = null;
        }

        Texture t = new Texture("sphereTexture",R.drawable.newImage);
        t.shouldRecycle(true);
              try {
                  material.addTexture(t);
              }
              catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }
```

Now I want to **change image with animation**.Please help how to animate **sphere**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

On click of your imageview, add an animation.

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); 
fadeIn.setDuration(500);

Image.setAnimation(fadeIn);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am talking about Texture. It is not simple ImageView. Bitmap is loaded on GLSurface using Rajawali Framework. It provides Sphere class to load images on GLSurface. I want to animate that sphere.